# Ordered list not working in Django

Tags: django

Im trying to using a ordered list in HTML to list the items in my querylist for some reason the ordering is not happening..
The list is diplayed but not ordering.

Here is my Django code,

```
<o1>
{% for t in teamrel %}
        <li> {{t.teamrelation}} </li>
{% endfor %}
</o1>
```

Here is my output in the HTML code,

Patron Relations Team Volunteer Relations Team Volunteer Relations Team

its not getting ordered.

Let me know your inputs.

Comment: Show us the generated markup.

Comment: Patron Relations Team Volunteer Relations Team Volunteer Relations Team . Its all displayed in 1 line

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your code sample appears to have an `<o1>` tag (o+ONE) instead of `<ol>` (o+L).

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `<o1>` shoudl be `<ol>`.

Otherwise, the `QuerySet` needs to be ordered correctly with an `queryset.order_by('foo')` call. Regardless of invalid tags, the output should be ordered.

You can print `print queryset.query` to see the actual ordering asked of the database.

Comment: The items are being listed but its all in 1 lines..I need each output  in a separate line.

Comment: @user1050619, check out the output HTML to see  why. Is it actually writing <ol><li>foo</li></ol> ? Are you positive you don't have a CSS reset and LI tags correctly rendered as block elements?